# Including scripts from another directory in php?

Tags: php, path, include

I have a very specific problem with including some scripts on my php project.

If i had a php script in my `main directory` and another script in a `second directory` inside the `main directory` i could just call it from the first script with this command:

```
include 'secondDirectory/myScript.php';\
```

What i have now is my `main directory` with 3 directories inside lets say:

```
Directory1
Directory2
HelpFunctions
```

In `Directory1` and `Directory2` are some scripts that use scripts from `HelpFunctions` too so i need to include them.

What i tried was to include them like this :

```
include '../HelpFunctions/myScript.php';
```

That means go back to the `main directory` from `Directory1` or `Directory2` and then go to `HelpFunctions` and include `myScript.php`

However i always get Warnings like these:

```
Warning: include(../HelpFunctions/scrapeFunction.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

Comment: You are including an include so you need to make it relative to the file located in `mainDirectory` or use absolute paths

Comment: 1: Check case, *nix systems are case-sensitive. 2: try `realpath()` http://uk3.php.net/realpath with the `__DIR__` constant e.g. `include realpath( __DIR__ . '/../HelpFunctions/myScript.php' );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably of position files

but u can try this

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

include "$root/HelpFunctions/myScript.php";
```